# Bash script to rename subfolder to include name of parent folder

Tags: beginner, file-system, bash, shell, sh

Here's the current structure of my directory.

```
.
├── Show 1
│   ├── Season 1
│   └── Season 2
├── Show 2
    ├── Season 1
    └── Season 2
```

I want to rename the Season folders to include the name of the Show. The desired structure looks like this :

```
.
├── Show 1
│   ├── Show 1 - Season 1
│   └── Show 1 - Season 2
├── Show 2
    ├── Show 2 - Season 1
    └── Show 2 - Season 2
```

Here's the script I wrote :

```bash
# Parse through all show folders.
for show in /Users/sanjeetsuhag/Desktop/* ; do
    # Check if it is a folder.
    if [ -d "$show" ]; then
        # Parse through all season folders.
        for season in $show/* ; do
            # Check if it is a folder.
            if [ -d "$season" ]; then               
                mv $season "$show/$(basename "$show") - $(basename "$season")" 
            fi      
        done
    fi
done
```

This is my first time scripting in Bash. Is there any thing I could improve ?

Comment: The `*` expansion on your `for` lines will cause problems if you have a space in a file name or directory since the shell splits things on whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

You should always double-quote variables that are used as filesystem paths.
This is the same script but with variables correctly double-quoted:

```
# Parse through all show folders.
for show in /Users/sanjeetsuhag/Desktop/*; do
    # Check if it is a folder.
    if [ -d "$show" ]; then
        # Parse through all season folders.
        for season in "$show"/*; do
            # Check if it is a folder.
            if [ -d "$season" ]; then               
                mv "$season" "$show/$(basename "$show") - $(basename "$season")" 
            fi      
        done
    fi
done
```

If you change the globs to end with `/`,
they will match only directories,
and so you can skip the directory checks:

```
for show in /Users/sanjeetsuhag/Desktop/*/; do
    for season in "$show"/*/; do
        mv "$season" "$show/$(basename "$show") - $(basename "$season")" 
    done
done
```

You could further optimize this by using pattern substitution instead of `basename`:

```
for show in /Users/sanjeetsuhag/Desktop/*/; do
    for season in "$show"/*/; do
        show=${show%/}
        season=${season%/}
        mv "$season" "$show/${show##*/} - ${season##*/}"
    done
done
```

The `${show%/}` is to shave off the trailing `/`,
and the `${show##*/}` is to delete everything until the last `/`.

Finally, instead of hardcoding the base path `/Users/sanjeetsuhag/Desktop`,
the script would be more reusable if you make that a command line parameter of the script.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid problems with spaces, as warned by @chicks, and most other hazardous characters as well, use double quotes often. The `find` utility also has a null-terminated line option `-print0` that helps with space and newline problems.

Here's a revamped script to try. Liberally commented as this is your first time into Bash scripting. Hope it helps you learn, and works as intended for your project.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Convert this directory structure:
# .
# ├── Show 1
# │   ├── Season 1
# │   └── Season 2
# └── Show 2
#     ├── Season 1
#     └── Season 2

# to this structure:
# .
# ├── Show 1
# │   ├── Show 1 - Season 1
# │   └── Show 1 - Season 2
# └── Show 2
#     ├── Show 2 - Season 1
#     └── Show 2 - Season 2   

# or, optionally to this structure:
# .
# ├── Show 1
# │   ├── Show 1 - Season 1
# │   │   ├── Show 1 - Season 1 - Episode 1
# │   │   ├── Show 1 - Season 1 - Episode 2
# │   │   └── Show 1 - Season 1 - Episode 3
# │   └── Show 1 - Season 2
# │       ├── Show 1 - Season 1 - Episode 1
# │       ├── Show 1 - Season 2 - Episode 2
# │       └── Show 1 - Season 2 - Episode 3
# └── Show 2
#     ├── Show 2 - Season 1
#     │   ├── Show 2 - Season 1 - Episode 1
#     │   ├── Show 2 - Season 1 - Episode 2
#     │   └── Show 2 - Season 1 - Episode 3
#     └── Show 2 - Season 2
#         ├── Show 2 - Season 2 - Episode 1
#         ├── Show 2 - Season 2 - Episode 2
#         └── Show 2 - Season 2 - Episode 3

# Is safe for spaces, and most other shell characters. Notable exception
# is the "\" charcter which WILL NOT work in the directoy names anywhere.
# !@#$&*"'{}[](): are all safe, seemingly international chars are as well.
#
# TEST on a backup copy first!! YMMV
#
# Get the show directory names using find
# -maxdepth 1 : limit search to 1 level - the current directory
# return values are ./show
# -type d : only find directories
# -print0 : print the list as null-terminate strings
# pipe stdout to read 
# -d $'\0' : make read use null as the line delimiter
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' show;
do
    # Skip the . directory entry for the shows
    if [ ! "." = "$show" ];
    then
        # Get the season directory names using find as above
        # This time use the current show directory as the base directory
        # Return values are ./show/season
        find "$show" -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' show_season;
        do
            # Strip of path from the show, in this case just ./
            show=$(basename "$show");
            # Skip the . directory entry for the seasons
            if [ ! "./$show" = "$show_season" ]
            then
                # Strip of the path from the season, in this case ./show/
                season_name=$(basename "$show_season");
                # Section to process the episodes in each season directory under the same name expansion scheme
                # Simply remove the comment marks in the first column, leave those that are deeper in.
                # Get the episode file names using the above logic again
                # This time use the current season directory as the base directory
                # Return values are ./show/season/episode
#                 find "$show_season" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' show_season_episode;
#                 do
#                     if [ ! "$show_season" = "$show_season_episode" ]
#                     then
#                         # Strip of the path from the episode, in this case ./show/season/
#                         episode_name=$(basename "$show_season_episode");
#                         # Rename the episode, the season directory has NOT been renamed yet!
#                         mv "$show_season_episode" "$show_season/$show - $season_name - $episode_name";
#                     fi
#                 done
                mv "$show_season" "$show/$show - $season_name";
            fi
        done
    fi
done
```